# »Einer der Ersten« im Plural

Tags: grammar, single-word-request, grammatical-number

Nehmen wir den Satz:

> Er ist *einer der Ersten*, die dieses Buch gelesen haben.

Wie würde dieser Satz für *wir* lauten?

> Wir sind [?] der Ersten, die dieses Buch gelesen haben.

Comment: Mhhh... wie wäre es mit "Wir sind unter den ersten"?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Der ähnlichste Plural ist wohl (*einer/eine/eines* hat keinen Plural):

> Wir sind einige der Ersten, die dieses Buch gelesen haben.

Weniger holprig finde ich allerdings:

> Wir sind unter den Ersten, die dieses Buch gelesen haben.

Eine weitere Alternative ist (Dank an Barth Zalewski):

> Wir gehören zu den Ersten, die dieses Buch gelesen haben.

---

In einigen Fällen (aber nicht in Deinem Beispiel) kann oder sollte man den Plural auch unverändert lassen, nämlich falls die Gruppe, für die *wir* steht, die erste Gruppe war, die etwas getan hat, z. B.:

> Acme war schon immer ein fortschrittliches Unternehmen. Wir sind eines der ersten, die auf das Doppeltransmogrifikationsverfahren umgestiegen sind.

Comment: Du stellst also auch fest, dass die Version mit **einige**, an die ich auch gedacht habe, holprig klingt. Was den zweiten Vorschlag betrifft, fällt mir dazu spontan noch ein: "Wir **gehören zu den ersten**". Danke für die Antwort.

Comment: @1Darco1: Völlig richtig. (Wobei diese Analogien leider nicht immer funktionieren, z. B. bei *anderen,* wo die Kleinschreibung bevorzugt (aber immerhin nur das) ist.)

Comment: -1 solange "Wir sind eine der ersten Adressen in der Branche." nicht erklärt ist.

Comment: @falkb: Ich habe ja nichts dagegen, den Punkt aufzunehmen; aber ist die Nicht-Erklärung eines Sonderfalls, der nicht gefragt wurde, wirklich Grund für eine −1?

Comment: Ich glaube, die Erklärung zum "Adressen"-Problem ist noch falsch. Man sagt "eine der Adressen" weil Adresse weiblich ist und "einer der Nutznießer", weil Nutznießer männlich ist. Der Schlüssel liegt doch einfach im Artikel des Singulars. Damit vermute ich sogar die ganze Antwort als falsch. Denn ich ziehe weiter den Rückschluss, dass es "einer der Ersten" heißen muss, weil es "der Erste" heißt, also "Erste" männlich ist. Dass es "eine der ersten Adressen" heißt, ist egal, da "ersten" hier nur ein Attribut für Adressen ist.

Comment: @falkb: Da war in der Tat ein Fehler, aber im Beispiel muss es *eines der ersten* lauten, da es ein Rückbezug auf Unternehmen ist, was Neutrum ist. Was Deinen Kommentar betrifft, so verstehe ich nicht, wieso *der Erste* gegenüber *die Erste* oder *das Erste* ausgezeichnet sein soll.

Comment: OK, stimmt, der Artikel ist bei "Erste" variabel. Aber zwingt uns genau das, "einige" zu verwenden?

Comment: @falkb: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24662/discussion-between-wrzlprmft-and-falkb).